# Return document where array element includes all values of input array | MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection of exercises:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Push Ups",
        "muscleGroups": ["Chest", "Shoulders", "Abs", "Biceps"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Sit Ups",
        "muscleGroups": ["Abs"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Pull Ups",
        "muscleGroups": ["Abs", "Biceps", "Back"]
    }
]
```

and an input array of `inputMuscleGroups`. I am trying to filter the exercises to where the `muscleGroups` array of the document has every element of the `inputMuscleGroups`.

For `inputMuscleGroups = ["Abs"]`, every document would return.

For `inputMuscleGroups = ["Abs", "Biceps"]`, output would be:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Push Ups",
        "muscleGroups": ["Chest", "Shoulders", "Abs", "Biceps"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Pull Ups",
        "muscleGroups": ["Abs", "Biceps", "Back"]
    }
]
```

For `inputMuscleGroups = ["Abs", "Shoulders", "Chest"]`, output would be:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Push Ups",
        "muscleGroups": ["Chest", "Shoulders", "Abs", "Biceps"]
    }
]
```

I have played around with `$in` but it appears these only return true if any of the input arrays match any of the document array.

Ideally I would want to do this within a `.find()` method as opposed to a `.aggregate()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `$all`

```
db.collection.find({
  muscleGroups: {
    $all: [
      "Abs",
      "Biceps"
    ]
  }
})
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3pntum-hj-6)**

Comment: Thanks for this! Perfect. How about if it's nested within an object? I can't seem to get it working: [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/b5RaSG7h9vt)

Comment: In that case, you need to go with aggregations